# LWJGL3. Странный графический артефакт OpenGL 3.x

Tags: java, opengl, графика, lwjgl

Всем привет. Работаю на java с lwjgl3. Столкнулся со странным артефактом, источник которого я не могу определить уже очень долгое время. Я рисую большую поверхность. Когда я подхожу к этой поверхности и направляю камеру вниз, нижняя часть текстуры моей поверхности начинает рваться и дергаться по мере движения моей камеры.

Для демонстрации артефакта я применю к поверхности узор шахматной доски, который рисуется шейдером

Вот так выглядит поверхность(просто стена):
[image: Фото1]

Я подошел к поверхности и направил камеру вниз(нижняя часть текстуры стены "порвалась" и сдвинулась):
[image: Фото2]

Если я наложу на стену png текстуру эффект будет тот же самый:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я перепроверил практически каждую часть моей программы, где потенциально может укрываться проблема. Пробовал отключать разные функции в шейдерах и пробовал играться с параметрами opengl, но все бесполезно. Кто-то сталкивался с таким? В чем вообще может быть проблема?

Comment: Потеря точности от слишком жирных текстурных координат? Попробуйте руками обрезать их через `mod(..., 1)` в шейдере перед передачей в `texture()`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Попробовал. Никаких результатов, к сожалению, это не дало

Comment: Возможно координата просто во float не влезает? Попробуйте на левый и правый край посмотреть. Если угадал, то край с нулевой координатой будет нормальный.

Comment: Я проверил. Действительно, на левом и правом краю стены артефактов не наблюдается. Учитывая это, какое есть возможное решение проблемы?

Comment: Если с обоих краев нормально, то я не угадал... В любом случае, просто поделить стену на два полигона?

Comment: Мне не кажется, что этот способ даст гарантированное решение проблемы. К тому же, эта проблема распространяется не только на стену, но и на остальные объекты моей сцены. Хотелось бы устранить артефакт раз и навсегда.

Comment: А какой длины стена, по сравнению с высотой?

Comment: Длина 500, высота 100. Получается, соотношение 5:1

Comment: Попробуйте 5 на 1, в 100 раз меньше.

Comment: Я уменьшил размер стены в 100 раз, но артефакт все еще проявляется.

Comment: Хммммм. Попробуйте на https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ спросить, может там знают. Я думаю все равно сведется к "полигоны слишком жирные", но все равно интересно, почему это не работает.

Comment: Хорошо. Спасибо! Как только решение будет найдено - я его выложу сюда